# How to display a specifc path from JSON tree depending on the leaves values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, search, tree

I have a question regarding displaying a path from a tree depending on the value of the leaf, for example I have the following JSON :

```
{
  "children": 
  [
    {
      "children": 
       [
         {
           "name": "Predict Conversion"
         }
       ],
       "name": "Browser ID in {1}"
    }, 
    {
      "children": 
       [
         {
           "name": "Predict Click"
         }
       ],
       "name": "Browser ID not in {1}"
    }
  ],
  "name": "Device Type ID in {1,3,4}" 
}
```

I want to display only the full path leading to the leaf with `value = "Predict Conversion"`

Comment: could you elaborate your question, because I don't get what depend on leaves value here...?

Comment: do you expect an output like `children[0].children[0].name`?

Comment: @n00dl3 I am parsing the output in order to create visualization with D3.JS
So for my example here I want to keep :
"name": "Device Type ID in {1,3,4}"
"name": "Browser ID in {1}"
"name": "Predict Conversion"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use recursion to loop over object. Use `Array.isArray` to test if value is of type `Array` and `typeof(obj)==="object"` for object.

Note: `typeof(obj)` will return `object` for both `Array` and for `Object`

```js
function searchInObj(obj, value, result) {
  
  // check for array and call for every item
  if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
    
    // primary flag for array.
    var r = false;
    obj.forEach(function(item, index) {
      
      // temporary flag for every iteration.
      var _r = searchInObj(item, value, result);
      if (_r) result.push(index)
      
      // if one of element returned true, array should return true.
      r = _r || r;
    });
    return r;
  } 
 
  // If Object, loop over properties
  else if (typeof(obj) === "object") {
    for (var k in obj) {
      
      // If object, check if property is Object/Array and call self.
      if (typeof(obj[k]) === "object") {
        var r = searchInObj(obj[k], value, result);
        if (r) result.push(k);
        return r;
      } 
      
      // If property is not Array/Object, match value
      else if (obj[k] === value) {
        result.push(k);
        return true;
      } 
      // If no match, return false
      else {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
}

var data = {
  "children": [{
    "children": [{
      "name": "Predict Conversion"
    }],
    "name": "Browser ID in {1}"
  }, {
    "children": [{
      "name": "Predict Click"
    }],
    "name": "Browser ID not in {1}"
  }],
  "name": "Device Type ID in {1,3,4}"
}

var result = []
searchInObj(data, "Predict Conversion", result);
document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(result.reverse(), 0, 4) + "</pre>");
```

Note: For small JSON, this will work but if your JSON is very long, this can be very expensive operation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion for it.

Quick example

```
var tree = {
"children": [{
    "children": [{
        "name": "Predict Conversion"
    }],
    "name": "Browser ID in {1}"
}, {
    "children": [{
        "name": "Predict Click"
    }],
    "name": "Browser ID not in {1}"
}],
"name": "Device Type ID in {1,3,4}" 
};

console.debug(tree);

function getPath(node, value){
   if(typeof node.children !== "undefined" && node.children !== null){
     for(var index in node.children){
       var name = getPath(node.children[index], value);
       if(name) {
         return node.name+"."+name;
       }
     }
   } else {
      if(node.name === value){
        return node.name;
      } 
      return false;
   }
}

console.log(getPath(tree, "Predict Conversion"))
```

Working example in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mujw5812/)